# In Python, how do I return a record multiple times based on a multi-value column

Tags: python, multivalue

In Python, I have the following data.  (Note: Below I display the data in a tabular format for easy reading, but the data is actually in a properly formatted csv file.)

```
ID,Movie,tag  
1,Fury,#action #war    
2,Shrek,#cartoon #comedy #fantasy  
3,Spaceballs,#comedy #space   
4,Cinderfella,#comedy   
5,Galaxy Quest,#comedy #space
```

I would like to get a list like the following.

```
#action   Fury
#cartoon  Shrek
#comedy   Cinderfella
#comedy   Galaxy Quest
#comedy   Shrek
#comedy   Spaceballs
#fantasy  Shrek
#space    Galaxy Quest
#space    Spaceballs
#war      Fury
```

Notice how there are only 5 movie titles, and there can be multiple tags per movie.  I need to explode the movie records into 10 lines.  So, a movie will have one line in the output per each tag it is assigned.  Fury is shown on 2 lines in the output. Shrek on 3, etc.

How do I do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide a few sample lines of the "properly formatted" .csv - people can't really help you if they don't know what the actual source data looks like. What have you tried yourself? What did you think of using and what problems did that give you?

Comment: Show your attempt. This is the very definition of "no research effort."  Few here will just sit down and write your code for you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by properly formatted csv.  The data is actually in a SQL database.  We collect the data with Python, Flask, and Javascript, and write it to the data base.  These are the three main columns or fields in the database.  I show a csv file only to make things simpler to explain.  The real problem is how to use a multi-value column and create a line per value.

Comment: I have no code to show, but I did research this.  I was unable to find code that made sense.  I am a novice to python and what I found seems awfully complex.  In the past, when I have looked up ways to solve problems, the solutions I found were fairly straightforward and easy to understand.  Not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments

Code:

```
m_list = []
with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    out = f.readlines()
    for line in out[1:]:  # skip the heading using 1:
        ID,Movie,tags = line.rstrip().split(',') # rstrip to remove newline character
        m_list += [[tag,Movie] for tag in tags.split()]
for m in m_list:
    print(m)
```

Output:

```
['#action', 'Fury']
['#war', 'Fury']
['#cartoon', 'Shrek']
['#comedy', 'Shrek']
['#fantasy', 'Shrek']
['#comedy', 'Spaceballs']
['#space', 'Spaceballs']
['#comedy', 'Cinderfella']
['#comedy', 'Galaxy Quest']
['#space', 'Galaxy Quest']
```

Comment: Thanks for this post.  It looks very straightforward.  I'll test and let you know if t worked for us.